# Topology Book Recommendation other than Munkres

Tags: general-topology

Could anyone recommend a good text on topology which would offer a higher level of abstraction than Munkres(and possibly cheaper)? I'd like to start with point set topology, but if the book could touch upon more subfields, that would be a plus. I'm an undergraduate who has taken courses in real analysis (on the level of rudin), combinatorics, complex analysis (Bak & newman), linear algebra and differential equations.

Comment: Munkres is really good, in my opinion. I think it's helpful to get a handle on specific examples of strange topologies, even if you go on to focus on situations that are nicer. Could you explain where you're looking for a higher level of abstraction?

Comment: "General Topology" by Stephen Willard